# macOS app built with Unity hangs upon launch after signing with codesign command in Terminal

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine, code-signing

I am trying to submit a macOS app built with Unity to the Mac App Store. I followed the instructions mentioned in the Unity documentation, [Delivering your application to the Mac App Store](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-PortToAppleMacStore.html).

I am able to run the Build command for macOS and get a .app bundle for my app. I am also able to launch it and it runs fine. However, after running the following `codesign` command (as mentioned in the linked document above), the app freezes upon launch and has to be force quitted. This is the `codesign` command line that I am running:

```
codesign -o runtime -f --deep -s '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: DEVELOPER NAME' --entitlements "GAMENAME.entitlements" "/AppPath/GAMENAME.app"
```

I have a paid (Individual) developer license with Apple, and have properly set up the certificates in keychain as mentioned in the document. I also managed to check that the app bundle was signed by running the command line:

```
codesign -dv --verbose=4 GAMENAME.app
```

Running the above command displays that it's signed with my 3rd Party Mac App Developer certificate.

I have tried looking for a way to *export* the Xcode project out from Unity app, so I can attempt to build and sign it with Xcode, but after searching the Web, I realized that Unity doesn't have support for exporting the Xcode project for macOS app yet (it can do the same for iOS).

I am running the current latest version of all the software, and the same are mentioned below:

1. macOS Catalina 10.15.1
2. Xcode 11.2.1
3. Unity 2019.2.13

My questions are:

- What is it that may be going wrong?
- What other avenues do I have?

I am looking for distributing the app *exclusively* via the Mac App Store for the time being. This is going to be a paid app (if that's relevant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are building the `.app` from the command line (using Unity's command line invocation), try building from the editor instead.

Confirm you are not building a 32 bit-only binary.

Try removing `-o runtime` from your codesign command, this is the only part of your process that differs from mine, and mine works fine.

Otherwise, when uploading to the App Store, I believe Xcode will sign for you. While this will not be different from `codesign`, Xcode may check if you accidentally blocked or otherwise misconfigured running binaries signed by you on your particular machine. You should test on a different machine or macOS VM.

Comment: Specifically, removing `-o runtime` from the codesign commandline did the trick.

Comment: The -o runtime will make it so that your app can only run if you notarize with Apple, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

My app is not targeting yet the app store so i'm building using my Developer ID Application certificate

I'm building now by xcode 13.2 a Unity 2021.1.28f1 produced xcodeproj on macOS 11.6.2

The produced app bundle is notarized during Archiving it (so using the -o runtime switch implicitely) and

- running seamlessly on macOS 11.6.2 even if no entitlements exception is used
- freezing on macOS 10.15.7 till the "Allow Unsigned Executable Memory" (com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory) entitlements is not added during the build

So now the solution was for me to add com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory to the app entitlements